# Application Exception in one class being returned to the calling class as an EJBTransactionRollbackException

Tags: java, exception, jpa, ejb, jpql

I am having some trouble regarding an exception being thrown when I don't want it to be. Here are my two classes:

```
public List<ErrorResponse> validate()
{
    List<ErrorResponse> errors = new ArrayList<ErrorResponse>();

    try
    {
        Users user = userManager.findByCompany(job.getCompanyId().getId());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ErrorCodes err = ErrorCodes.CODE101;
        errors.add(new ErrorResponse(err.getCode(), err.getMessage()));
    }
}


public Users findByCompany(Integer companyId) 
        throws UserNotFoundException, UsernameNotProvidedException
{
    if (username == null)
    {
        throw new UserUsernameNotProvidedException();
    }

    TypedQuery<Users> query = em.createNamedQuery("Users.findByCompany", Users.class);
    query.setParameter("companyId", companyId);
    try
    {
        Users result = query.getSingleResult();
        return result;
    }
    catch (NoResultException e)
    {
        throw new UserNotFoundException();
    }
    catch (NonUniqueResultException e)
    {
        throw new UserNotFoundException();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new UserNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Ok - so the validate() method calls the findByCompany() method (in another class). The exception being thrown is the runtime 'NonResultException' (which is correct) in the findByCompany() method. This is then CAUGHT in the same method, and my application Exception 'UserNotFoundException' is thrown. This should now propagate to the validate() method, where it should be caught in the 'catch(Exception e)'. However instead, the 'catch(Exception e)' in validate() is catching an 'EJBTransactionRolledBackException' instead, which is not what I want - The application should continue if no results are found.

Surely by catching the runtime exception and throwing my application exception (and again, catching that in the validate() method), the rollback should be avoided?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know that you've accepted the answer, but I would like to know what kind of exception is (or was at the moment you wrote the question) 'UserNotFoundException'? I'm confused, It seems to be a checked a exception (is declared it in the signature's method), if so, I don't see why your transaction is rollback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions that extend `RuntimeException` or `RemoteException` and are not annotated with `@ApplicationException` are considered system exceptions and are therefore wrapped in an `EJBException`.

You may either want to throw a checked Exception (probably not) or annotate your exception class.

This can also be configured inside a deployment descriptor XML, but I am not aware of the details.